# Knockout binding failed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze, durandal-2.0

Starting to pull my hair off! 
I am creating an object using Breeze (the metadata is coming from a web api server).

The server side looks like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

On the client side, I create an entity using Breeze:

```
var product = ko.observable();
product(manager.createEntity('Product', {name:'', description:''}));
```

On the UI, I have the following:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text"" class="form-control"  data-bind="value: name" >
    <textarea class="form-control" data-bind="value: description"></textarea>
</div>
```

The problem is: knockout binds to the name no problem but not to the description! Here is what I get in the console:

> Unable to process binding "value: function (){return description }"
>   Message: description is not defined;

What I don't get is: the `product` is properly created and contains all needed properties as shown in Chrome debug view:

[image]

Comment: Can you post more context from your html? How is your `product` bound?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? Assuming the server-side data arrives fine, you can use a simple JS object on the fiddle as a substitute for your server-side data to simulate your situation.

Comment: Can you try : <textarea class="form-control" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON($data)"></textarea> ?

Comment: @Damien Same problem, I get `An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable. `

Comment: @nemesv Durandal does the binding for me.

Comment: @EfrainReyes It is more difficult to create a jsFiddle using Breeze because Breeze relies on the metadata being available, so if he is using EF and exposing the metadata from the context provider he would have to rewrite a bunch of stuff

Comment: @GETah Nemesv is asking for the context that wraps your HTML shown above, aka a with: binding or a foreach: or something

Comment: If the `ko.toJSON($data)` is not working you can try out to console.log the `$data` so try it with :  `<textarea class="form-control" data-bind="value: console.log($data)"></textarea>` And you should post the part of your html where you have the `product` property...

Comment: @PWKad Done, please see my edited html code. The bindings are directly done on the view model, not `foreach` and such

Comment: @GETah if they are directly done in the view model than please show your view model.

Comment: What version of knockout are you using?

Comment: @PWKad Oh man!!! Thank you very much for pointing me out to the bindings. I just found out that my view binds to the parent viewmodel which happens to have `name` property and not the `product`. This is why Durandal is complaining about the description only :( *I suggest you copy this as an answer and I will accept*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to bind to the proper context.  As @nemesv pointed out in the comments using a console.log() function directly inside of your textarea should be sufficient to find what properties are available.

Given that you are using Durandal 2.0 you can also see what is available in the bound context using the console.  Durandal's system logger actually outputs the currently bound context directly into the console.  It appears to show you which module was loaded and the context of that module.

```
Binding views/patients/overview/index > Object { activate: function }
```

Expanding the object will show you what is currently available as well as any child properties.

Answer (score -1):

can you try
    <textarea class="form-control" data-bind="value: description**()**"></textarea>